# End-to-end testing with Protractor not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, batch-file, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am runnung the angular-seed project(code is located [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/tree/69c9416c8407fd5806aab3c63916dfcf0522ecbc)), I installed Node.js, Jasmine(with `C:\Users\nradisic\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\angular-seed-master>npm install jasmine`) and Protractor(with `C:\Users\nradisic\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\angular-seed-master>npm install protractor`). I am trying to run End-to-End tests with Protractor by runnung e2e-test.bat with content:

```
@echo off

REM Windows script for running e2e tests
REM You have to run server first
REM
REM Requirements:
REM - NodeJS (http://nodejs.org/)
REM - Protractor (npm install -g protractor)

set BASE_DIR=%~dp0
webdriver-manager update
protractor "%BASE_DIR%\..\config\protractor-conf.js" %*
```

and protractor-conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

  specs: [
    '../test/e2e/*.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/app/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

When I update and run webdriver-manager with `C:\Users\nradisic\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\angular-seed-master\node_modules\protractor\bin>node webdriver-manager start` and after that start the e2e-test.bat I get error messages:

> 'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   
>   'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How to fix this?

My OS is Windows 8.1. I am running a project from Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: npm install selenium-webdriver -> does this work from command prompt?
And do you have selenium server running?

Comment: I installed selenium-webdriver, but i don't know how to start it. I tried running npm start from the base directory, but it does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever try `npm install -g protractor`? I found it in the REM of e2e-test.bat.

The running result:
`>e2e-test.bat`
`Updating selenium standalone`
`downloading https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar...`
`Updating chromedriver`
`downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.13/chromedriver_win32.zip...`
`chromedriver_2.13.zip downloaded to C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver_2.13.zip`
`selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar downloaded to C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar`